# Idempotence of Lawvere-Tierney topology induced by Grothendieck topology

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I'm hoping someone can elucidate a step in the proof of V.1.2 in Mac Lane & Moerdijk's *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category and $J$ a Grothendieck topology. $J$ induces an endomorphism $j$ on the subobject classifier $\Omega$ in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$ by setting, for a sieve $S\in\Omega(c)$, $$j_c(S)=\{f:\mathrm{dom}(f)\to c\:|\:f^*S\in J(\mathrm{dom}(f))\}.$$ The above mentioned proof in *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* establishes that this map is a natural transformation and, moreover, a Lawvere-Tierney topology. I find most of the proof fairly straightforward, except when it comes to idempotence.

Mac Lane & Moerdijk's proof explains why $j_c(S)\subset j_cj_c(S)$, which is clear enough, and then for the inclusion $j_cj_c(S)\subset j_c(S)$ they say,

> Conversely, if $g\in j_cj_c(S)$, then $j_c(S)$ covers $g$. But for each $h\in j_c(S)$ one has that $S$ covers $h$. Hence, by the transitivity property of a Grothendieck topology, $S$ covers $g$, i.e., $g\in j_c(S)$.

(Here, "$S$ covers $f$" is a synonym for "$f^*S\in J(\mathrm{dom}(f))$".)

My intuition says it's obvious that transitivity has to be invoked for this, but I can't quite see *how* it's doing the work here; I'm missing whatever dot connects the "hence" with the bits before it. **Can someone clarify how the transitivity property gives the conclusion here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me reword this more explicitly.

Recall the transitivity axiom for a Grothendieck topology in arrow form:

> (iiia) If $S$ covers an arrow $f:D\to C$, and $R$ is a sieve on $C$ which covers all arrows of $S$, then $R$ covers $f$

Also recall that by definition, $j_C(S) = \{g|S\text{ covers }g\}$.

Now to show $j_Cj_C(S)\subset j_C(S)$ we need to show that for $g$ covered by $j_C(S)$ (ie. $g\in j_Cj_C(S)$), $S$ also covers $g$. Now by definition, $S$ covers all arrows of $j_C(S)$. Since $j_C(S)$ covers $g$, it follows by transitivity that $S$ covers $g$.